# Why does AWS Lambda experience a consistent 10-second delay for an unresolvable domain using requests.get?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests

I'm experiencing a peculiar behavior when trying to make an HTTP request to unresolved domain names from an AWS Lambda function using the `requests` library in Python.

When I attempt to make a request using:

```
response = requests.get('https://benandjerry.com', timeout=(1,1))
```

In AWS Lambda, it consistently takes around 10 seconds before it throws an error. However, when I run the same code on my local environment, it's instant. I've verified this using logs and isolated tests.

I've considered potential issues like Lambda's cold starts, Lambda runtime differences, and even VPC configurations, but none seem to be the root cause.

I also tried using curl to access the domain, and it instantly returned with Could not resolve host: benandjerry.com.

Last point, this is happening on specific unresolved domain names, not all of them.

Here's a sample:

- http://seen.ma/
- benandjerry.com
- clenyabeauty.com
- gong.com

FYI, you can easily replicate the issue by creating a python3.9 Lambda on AWS & adding the following code:

```
import json
from botocore.vendored import requests
import urllib.request
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    url = 'http://benandjerry.com'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, proxies=None,verify=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Questions:

1. What could be causing this consistent 10-second delay in AWS Lambda
   for an unresolvable domain using requests?
2. How can I get AWS Lambda to instantly recognize that the domain is unresolvable, similar to the behavior on my local machine?

Comment: Updates: I migrated my whole function to httpx & it has exactly the same issue except it's not 10 seconds, it's consistent 30 seconds delay.

Comment: What's the timeout you had set for the lambda?

Comment: @RobinThomas it's set to 60 seconds. The lambda is not timing out though, it's just the error of the invalid domain name that takes 10 seconds.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your trials with VPCs?
Did you try to completely remove it from a VPC?

My guess is that you have some DNS configuration that causes it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver-overview-DSN-queries-to-vpc.html

Comment: @saart, we don't use VPC at all so it shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: What version of Python are you using for your Lambda?

Comment: iirc the `requests` library does some specific things with the env for determining proxies and what not. Try taking a look specifically at your `*_proxy` settings, and might also be worth setting `trust_env=False` to verify. https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/src/requests/sessions.py#L436-L438C30

Comment: @stdunbar we are using python3.9 but I tried 3.7 as well.

Comment: @flakes great suggestion! I tried response = requests.get(url, proxies=None,verify=False) but no success..

Comment: Maybe look into DNS resolution? I would play around with the `dns.resolver` library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to the AWS DNS taking up to 10 seconds trying to resolve the domain. If you want more control over the DNS resolution, you can implement a custom requests [Transport Adapter](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters) to do the DNS resolution yourself—which allows you to better customize the timeout.

```bash
pip install dnspython
```

```py
import urllib
import requests
import dns.resolver


class CustomDnsResolverHttpAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def resolve(self, hostname):
        resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver(configure=False)
        resolver.timeout = 5
        resolver.lifetime = 5

        resolver.nameservers = [
            "1.1.1.1"  # cloudflare dns
            , "8.8.8.8" # google dns
            # , "169.254.78.1"  # aws dns
        ]

        answer = resolver.resolve(hostname, "A", lifetime=5)

        if len(answer) == 0:
            return None

        return str(answer[0])

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        connection_pool_kwargs = self.poolmanager.connection_pool_kw

        result = urllib.parse.urlparse(request.url)
        resolved_ip = self.resolve(result.hostname)

        if result.scheme == "https" and resolved_ip:
            request.url = request.url.replace(
                "https://" + result.hostname,
                "https://" + resolved_ip,
            )
            connection_pool_kwargs["server_hostname"] = result.hostname  # SNI
            connection_pool_kwargs["assert_hostname"] = result.hostname

            # overwrite the host header
            request.headers["Host"] = result.hostname
        else:
            # clear these headers if they were set in a previous TLS request
            connection_pool_kwargs.pop("server_hostname", None)
            connection_pool_kwargs.pop("assert_hostname", None)

            # overwrite the host header
            request.headers["Host"] = result.hostname

        return super(CustomDnsResolverHttpAdapter, self).send(request, **kwargs)



http_agent = requests.Session()
http_agent.mount("http://", CustomDnsResolverHttpAdapter())
http_agent.mount("https://", CustomDnsResolverHttpAdapter())

response = http_agent.get("https://benandjerry.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

- If the dns name cannot be resolved, it will cause a timeout when you make a http request with the "request" python library . So check first your dns resolution using the following command line:

```
nslookup your-domain.com
```

If you notice some latency here you may fix it by using dnspython library. Here some examples: https://www.dnspython.org/examples/

- AWS lambda has a cold start and some additional time may be noticed during the initialisation process. This may explain your 10-second delay. To fix this you can create a warm-up mechanism by invoking your lambda function periodically.

Keep in Mind that you can contact the AWS Support for assistance if you've no solution for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with how DNS is set up - if the hostname is not resolvable via AWS DNS, the Lambda environment is set up with secondary and tertiary DNS. It has a timeout to receive a response from these set to 10 seconds.

More information is available [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-intermittent-consistent-dns-error)